# Create, Update and Delete operations in pygeoapi

Tags: python, geojson, ogc

It looks like the [GeoJSON provider](https://github.com/geopython/pygeoapi/blob/b61404d610060361e931e8abbd05b9ba34d9cc00/pygeoapi/provider/geojson.py) is the first, and currently the only, provider to implement `create`, `update` and `delete` operations.

I can't see an example for how to enable these operations in the `pygeoapi-config.yml` file. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi, I just edited the tags on this question because it was somehow marked as [tag:untagged] which is a [special tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372558/no-question-should-be-untagged) that is assigned when the original tags are somehow deleted, leaving the question in an invalid state without any tags. I took my best guess as to the correct tags, but you might want to [edit] the question and fix them.  I ask because there's currently an effort to sort these out, see [this meta discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399176).

Comment: The new `pygeoapi` tag seems to periodically be removed since other questions have not yet been added with this tag.  It's important to keep the tag because most SO users cannot create the tag themselves and it is listed as a support option here: https://pygeoapi.io/community/#stack-overflow

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, `create`, `update` and `delete` transactions are [not supported](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/pygeoapi/2019-December/000046.html) through `pygeoapi`, (in part because these are not yet support as part of the OGC API Features specification). This is being discussed in an issue on GitHub:

> **[support for transactions #107](https://github.com/geopython/pygeoapi/issues/107)**
>
> "OGC-API-Features currently [does not offer a specification for transactions yet](https://github.com/opengeospatial/ogcapi-features/issues/140) ...."

Comment: Update: as of September 2022 pygeoapi supports API Transactions.  See https://docs.pygeoapi.io/en/latest/transactions.html for more information.